# Temporal Logic and Access Control Models

Tags: lo.logic, formal-modeling, linear-temporal-logic, se.software-engineering

What is the best way to describe the semantics of a new access control model?. I heard the temporal logic is the way to go. Is it true?

Comment: I'm not an expert, can you define what "a new access control model" is (or add some references)? This site is for research level questions (see [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details), so we hope that you already know well papers like [this](http://spdp.dti.unimi.it/papers/tods-temporal.ps) and [this](http://spdp.dti.unimi.it/papers/sam-fosad.pdf) :)

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi Hi, thanks. Yes I know about access controls and their related papers. Question here is: What is the best *formal* way to define the semantics of an access control model? Is it linear temporal logic or am I barking under a wrong tree?.

Comment: @asgharashgari: If the access control model has temporal aspects in it, then temporal logic is the way to go. Martin Abadi (among others) has done research on formal/logical models of access control. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of publication on extending and or formalizing RBAC/SOD with LTL or other flavors of temporal logics, not sure of other AC models. Google Scholar (or simple google) search with yield a bunch of articles. Most of them might be not sufficiently formal for somebody like yourself, yet might be of some interest. Not sure is LTL the best way. Yet for a hammers everything is a nail, so if temporal logic is your specialty you might be more successful with it than without.. Consider also traditional programming language semantics approaches such as Z and alike, Game Theoretical/Modular/HyperProperties, dedicated logics. Totally depends on your AC.

Check example articles and see what you feel is the way
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066109003107